# How can I copy data from CSV to database with Tables and Composite Types using Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I have redesigned a given database to an Object-Relational Database, I've created tables and composite types with Postgres and I have a hard time copying values from CSV that I've used for the previous form of the db, to the redesigned one due to the existence of composite types in the place of some tables. Is there any version of the "copy" query that fits for tables that include composite types?

Comment: Consider posting the data you're having a problem with and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Sometimes it's just easier to create a table mimicking the csv file, import to it, then use sql to copy to the real table.

Answer (score 0):

"The data to be entered for the composed type column are to be enclosed within
paretheses. The single sub-columns are to be comma separated."

```
COPY atable( somedata,ct ) FROM STDIN;
```

Copied from (edited for grammar): http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200712261431.04689.regmeplease@gmail.com